# Render MVC Partial View in non-MVC project from an MVC referenced DLL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

I know from that subject you're probably thinking "what the hell".  But let me explain!

I have two projects:
MyMVCWebsite - An MVC Website running on windows azure
MyWebsiteWorker - A separate DLL project running on a separate windows azure worker role.  This references MyMVCWebsite as a DLL as it uses some of its code.

I have a controller called Email and the actions are the different types of emails we send, for example /Email/DailyNewsletter(model: userDetails)

The controller exposes a method RenderPartialViewAsString which would allow me to render /Email/DailyNewsletter/userDetails into a string, which i could then send in the HtmlBody of the email.

This is all fine and dandy, if I want to send these emails from the webserver, but I don't.

I want to be able to render the partial view from MyWebsiteWorker using something like:

```
For each user in usersToEmail
  Dim _con as new EmailController
  SendEmail(user.emailAddress, _con.RenderPartialViewAsString(user))
next
```

Obviously this doesn't work (you can't even create a new instance of EmailController)

I want to do it this way because there could be 1000's of emails to send, and I don't want that load putting on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Why build the email sending into the website in the first place?  Just make it part of the external app.  If you want to use Razor views for your email template then install something like FluentEmail to do this.  It installs it's own version of the Razor engine to do view rendering.  I don't see why it wouldn't work in a non-web project.

http://lukencode.com/2010/04/11/fluent-email-in-net/

Answer (score 0):

I my bit a little late to help you, but i'm leaving this here so this is responded.

I had the same problem in a project, the way I did it was using the [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/). For this you have use the whole view in a string and then parse it with the RazorEngine and your Model, this has some limitations of course.

I have my view in a blob from azure storage and the worker role downloads it and then parses it with the model.

Downloading the page form azure:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(appSets["LocalEnvironmentStorageConnection"]);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(appSets["LocalEnvironmentContainer"]);
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("LocalEnvironmentBlob");
string page;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
     blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
     page = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

Do the logic so the model has the right information and then parse the page with the RazorEngine

```cs
string html = Razor.Parse(page, model);
```

In my case I was using ElasticEmail to send my emails, just had to copy the code from the website to the worker role an then send it

```cs
_client.Send("", user.email, subject, html, offset);
```

Hope it helps some one